Totally blocked by expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
I'm new to solana development and anchor to start. I might just be missing something but I keep getting stuck with increasingly frustrating build errors.
For context i've copied the nft metadata pointer implementation from this repo
I started with the dependencies found in the related Cargo.toml file but due spl-token-metadata-interface = { version = "0.2.1"} being yanked I had to update which led me to running the commands:
cargo tree (Which indicated to run the following commands)
cargo upgrade --incompatibles

cargo upgrade --pinned

This got me to this dependencies config
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.30.1", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = { version = "0.30.1" }
session-keys = { version = "2.0.5", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
solana-program = "2.0.3"
spl-token-2022 = { version="4.0.1", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
spl-token = { version = "6.0.0", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
spl-token-metadata-interface = { version = "0.4.0"}
spl-type-length-value = "0.5.0"
spl-program-error = "0.5.0"

and all seemed great until I ran
cargo clean                  
cargo update --aggressive
anchor clean
anchor build

Which outputs:
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
  --> src/state.rs:67:99
   |
39 | ) -> Result<TlvIndices, ProgramError> {
   |      -------------------------------- expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
67 |             pod_from_bytes::<Length>(&tlv_data[tlv_indices.length_start..tlv_indices.value_start])?;
   |                                                                                                   ^ the trait `From<spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<TlvError>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
             <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
   = note: required for `Result<TlvIndices, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> src/state.rs:109:14
    |
80  | ) -> Result<(Vec<ArrayDiscriminator>, usize), ProgramError> {
    |      ------------------------------------------------------ expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
109 |             )?;
    |              ^ the trait `From<spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<TlvError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
    = note: required for `Result<(Vec<ArrayDiscriminator>, usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> src/state.rs:141:80
    |
127 | ) -> Result<&[u8], ProgramError> {
    |      --------------------------- expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
141 |     let length = pod_from_bytes::<Length>(&tlv_data[length_start..value_start])?;
    |                                                                                ^ the trait `From<spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<TlvError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
    = note: required for `Result<&[u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/state.rs:216:9
    |
214 |     ) -> Result<&V, ProgramError> {
    |          ------------------------ expected `Result<&V, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` because of return type
215 |         let data = get_bytes::<V>(self.get_data(), repetition_number)?;
216 |         pod_from_bytes::<V>(data)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, found `spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: `spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` and `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/program_error.rs:15:1
note: `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/program_error.rs:14:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/state.rs:333:9
    |
331 |     ) -> Result<&mut V, ProgramError> {
    |          ---------------------------- expected `Result<&mut V, solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` because of return type
332 |         let data = self.get_bytes_with_repetition_mut::<V>(repetition_number)?;
333 |         pod_from_bytes_mut::<V>(data)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`, found `spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: `spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` and `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
note: `spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/program_error.rs:15:1
note: `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` is defined in crate `solana_program`
   --> src/program_error.rs:14:1
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> src/state.rs:362:85
    |
362 |         let length = pod_from_bytes::<Length>(&self.data[length_start..value_start])?;
    |                                                                                     ^ the trait `From<spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<TlvError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
    = note: required for `Result<&mut [u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> src/state.rs:387:60
    |
387 |         let extension_ref = pod_from_bytes_mut::<V>(buffer)?;
    |                                                            ^ the trait `From<spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<TlvError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
    = note: required for `Result<(&mut V, usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> src/state.rs:439:88
    |
439 |                 pod_from_bytes_mut::<Length>(&mut self.data[length_start..value_start])?;
    |                                                                                        ^ the trait `From<spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<TlvError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
    = note: required for `Result<(&mut [u8], usize), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> src/state.rs:490:97
    |
490 |         let length_ref = pod_from_bytes_mut::<Length>(&mut self.data[length_start..value_start])?;
    |                                                                                                 ^ the trait `From<spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<TlvError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
    = note: required for `Result<&mut [u8], solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
   --> src/state.rs:556:84
    |
547 | ) -> Result<(), ProgramError> {
    |      ------------------------ expected `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError` because of this
...
556 |         usize::try_from(*pod_from_bytes::<Length>(&data[length_start..value_start])?)?
    |                                                                                    ^ the trait `From<spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `solana_program::program_error::ProgramError`
    |
    = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
    = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<u64>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<TlvError>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<std::io::Error>>
              <solana_program::program_error::ProgramError as From<solana_program::pubkey::PubkeyError>>
    = note: required for `Result<(), solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, spl_pod::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `spl-type-length-value` (lib) due to 10 previous errors

From here i've tried troubleshooting a few things, but it seems that there could be some dependency issue and not necessarily and issue with the code.
local dep versions:
rustup 1.27.1 (54dd3d00f 2024-04-24)
solana-cli 1.18.18 (src:83047136; feat:4215500110, client:SolanaLabs)
anchor-cli 0.30.1

halpppp.

You'll need to use the dependencies required by Anchor, otherwise your project will pull in two major versions of solana-program and then have a hard time disambiguating the two.
Here are the dependencies that you'll need to use for your project:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.30.1", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = { version = "0.30.1" }
session-keys = { version = "2.0.5", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
solana-program = "1.18"
spl-token-2022 = { version = "3.0.4", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
spl-token = { version = "4.0.3", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
spl-token-metadata-interface = { version = "0.3.5"}
spl-type-length-value = "0.4.6"
spl-program-error = "0.4.4"


May be a stupid question but how did you locate the versions? Did you just look at the deps for the create version for anchor?
Thank you x1000000!

That's exactly what I did haha
